# When I copy external database on asset folder, it remove automatically after running application in android programming

Tags: android

I build a project for testing external data base, but i faced an unexpected problem, when i run project database folder inside of asset folder remove automatically.
thats why exteranl database tables don't copy in internal database. How can I solve it??
My codes:
mainactivity.java file

```
package com.toseeit.dbtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private database db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db= new database(this);
    db.database();
}
}
```

database.java class

```
package com.toseeit.dbtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;

/**
 * Created by Jamshidi on 06/07/2016.
 */
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//address of internal database
public final String path = "data/data/com.toseeit.dbtest/databases/";
//Name of internal database
public final String Name = "dbtest";
// this variable use when we want to copy database
public SQLiteDatabase mydb;
private final Context mycontext;

public database(Context context) {
    super(context, "dbtest", null, 1);
    mycontext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//general db for check and copy database
public void database() {
    boolean checkdb = chckdb();
    if (checkdb == true) {


    } else {

        // with bellow code we making place for database which can save copydatabase
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {

            copydatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
public void open(){
    mydb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + Name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
public void close(){
    mydb.close();
}

//this function check internal path if is there database or not
public boolean chckdb() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + Name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
    return db != null ? true : false;

}

//this function will use when we want copy info from database inside of project / IOException is for filling activities
public void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    // this place is internal database address and it's name
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(path + Name);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    //this place is external database name
    InputStream myInpout = mycontext.getAssets().open("dbtest");
    while ((length = myInpout.read(buffer)) > 0) {

        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myInpout.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}


}
```

Comment: what You mean with "removed"? I don´t think that your database inside asset folder gets deleted....maybe it´s a large database? How is the file size of this db?

Comment: you are right , I added database in wrong place (inside of intermadiate folder) , now i created in app\build\src\main then the problem solved.